# Do not redirect to login page after session timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise 3.1.1 and trying to redirect to a certain page after session times out
just wondering why this [tip](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Do-not-redirect-to-login-page-after-session-timeout) is not working for me?
I have added this [code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Do-not-redirect-to-login-page-after-session-timeout) but still redirecting to login page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect a user on homepage after session is expired.

In application_controller paste this code

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
  root_url
end
```

In devise.rb file uncomment this line

```
config.timeout_in = 2.minutes
```

Set your time and restart server.